# Replace AD Group in Exchange with Users in that AD Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

We have to migrate to Microsoft Azure and since Azure cant handle AD Groups in Exchange I have to get the members of a spezifc group and then add them to exchange. So I thought I can achive this with powershell.

The princip:

I have the Mailbox Name and the Group that has to be extracted in a csv like this:

Mailbox1 GroupForMailbox1

Mailbox2 GroupForMailbox2

Mailbox2 GroupForMailbox2

I know how to extract all users out of a group:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "GroupForMailbox1" -Recursive
```

But the problem is, that there is a Group in this Group which I dont want to get the users out of it. Let me call that "ExcludedGroup". How can I get all AD Group Members except the ones of the Group "ExcludedGroup"?

Then I have to put those AD Members to the specific mailbox:

```
$Users= "Users that I've got out of the upper command"

foreach ($Users){

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Mailbox1" -User $Users Accessright Fullaccess -InheritanceType all
}
```

But i cant fit everything of this in one Script because of lack of knowledge.

And I cant find something on the internet althought it is a real problem with azure.

I thought someone out there can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#Sample data
$csv = @"
Mailbox,GroupName
Mailbox1,GroupForMailbox1
Mailbox2,GroupForMailbox2
Mailbox2,GroupForMailbox2
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

#Uncomment to import file
#$csv = Import-CSV -Path MyInputFile.csv

$ExcludedUsers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "ExcludedGroup" -Recursive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $mailbox = $_.Mailbox

    #Get members for group
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.GroupName -Recursive |
    #Remove unwanted users and keep only user objects (remove groups, computers etc.)
    Where-Object { ($ExcludedUsers -notcontains $_.SamAccountName) -and ($_.objectclass -eq 'user') } |
    ForEach-Object {
        #Grant each group member permission
        Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $mailbox -User $_.SamAccountName -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks for sharing this script :)